# "Filter" array of object using an object

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of object:

```
const users = [
    {name: "John", age: "20", houses:{mountain: true, beach: false, penthouse: true, countryhouse: false}},
    {name: "Paul", age: "32", houses:{mountain: false, beach: false, penthouse: true, countryhouse: true}},
    {name: "Michael", age: "53", houses:{mountain: true, beach: true, penthouse: false, countryhouse: false}}
]
```

And the following

```
const properties = {mountain: true, beach: true, penthouse: false, countryhouse: false}
```

What I am trying to do is use the object properties to filter out the users that do not meet the criteria (when one of the property is toggled to true or more than one).

I have tried many different ways with different mixed results (including using the keys in properties object to create a single object containing just the keys that have the true boolean value) but I do get some very weird results depending on the method. What would be the best way to go by it ?
I would like to return an array of objects only fitting the criterias from the object properties

Comment: Can you edit in one of the ways you’ve tried and what it produced? It might have been nearly right =)

Comment: you should use the filter function for Array in JS - var youngsters = people.filter(function (item) {
 return item.age < 30;
});

Comment: @DawoodAwan I would also try to avoid to manually enter the key from the object and loop through in case the data changes (if i decide to add swimming pool for example to a user)

Comment: Please take a tour of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). have a look at [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) Also on how to [Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Be sure to [search thoroughly](/search) before posting. Just about every possible "filter an array based on X" question has been asked and thoroughly answered.

Comment: @NinaScholz true is not good !

Comment: Your test function should loop through `properties`, testing if all of them match what's in the current element being filtered.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder done that already for the last two days, however none of the answers can to do this without typing in some of the values, I would rather loop through in case data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate the array. In the filter callback use [Array#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) with [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that all properties in `houses` are equal to those the `properties` constant:

```js
const users = [{name: "John", age: "20", houses:{mountain: true, beach: false, penthouse: true, countryhouse: false}},{name: "Paul", age: "32", houses:{mountain: false, beach: false, penthouse: true, countryhouse: true}},{name: "Michael", age: "53", houses:{mountain: true, beach: true, penthouse: false, countryhouse: false}}];

const properties = {mountain: true, beach: true, penthouse: false, countryhouse: false};

const result = users.filter(({ houses }) => 
  Object.keys(properties).every((key) => properties[key] === houses[key])
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thats perfect, exactly what I've been looking for !